# How to set equivalent of 'docker run -m 2048' in docker compose yml file

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I can run a docker image with `docker run -m 2048 <imagename>` which runs a Windows container with 2048MB of ram.

However, when I try the equivalent that I can find in a docker compose file `mem_reservation: 2048M` I get an error:

> Windows does not support MemoryReservation

How can I assign my docker container 2048MB of RAM when running it from docker compose, the equivalent of docker run -m ?

The application I am testing requires the machine to report 2GB of RAM as a minimum, and without any memory settings in the yml file the container only reports 1GB RAM to my application.

Comment: How about `mem_limit`?

Comment: @SiHa I've added more info, I want it to report a certain amount of memory, I would imagine mem_limit is for imposing a maximum amount of RAM, not for defining the minimum/amount of RAM to use, isn't it?

Comment: I see. Yes, it is.

Comment: Compose file v2 `mem_limit` should be the direct equivalent to `docker run -m`.  Neither option "assigns" memory to the container or limits how much of the host memory it could see.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes thank you, tried it and it works perfectly. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

David Maze's solution using `mem_limit` has since been deprecated. The current recommended way to do this is to use [deploy.limits.memory](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#memory)

```
services:
  frontend:
    image: awesome/webapp
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
          pids: 1
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```